How to properly create CMAP for embedded font in PDF?
I'm trying to "manually" build a PDF and i need to use Times New Roman font for Cyrillic text. I read *.ttf file and embedded it in a PDF file:
5 0 obj
<</Length 915932 /Length1 915932 >>
stream
 ...font data...
endstream
endobj

Font object:
9 0 obj
<<
/Encoding /Identity-H
/ToUnicode 7 0 R
/Subtype /Type0
/Type /Font
/DescendantFonts [8 0 R]
/BaseFont /YAZWPA+Times-Roman
>>
endobj

Descendant font object:
8 0 obj
<<
/Type /Font
/Subtype /CIDFontType2
/BaseFont /YAZWPA+Times-Roman
/CIDToGIDMap /Identity
/CIDSystemInfo
<<
/Ordering (Identity)
/Registry (Adobe)
/Supplement 0
>>
/FontDescriptor 6 0 R
/DW 250
/W [0 [777.83203 0 0 0 333.00781] 585 [722.16797] 604 [472.16797 0 0 443.84766 0 0 535.15625 0 0 0 632.8125 0 0 0 500 0 437.01172]]
>>
endobj

Font descriptor:
6 0 obj
<<
/Type /FontDescriptor
/FontName /YAZWPA+Times-Roman
/Ascent 891
/Descent -216
/StemV 0
/CapHeight 662
/Flags 6
/FontBBox [-568 -307 2046 1039]
/AvgWidth 401
/MaxWidth 2000
/XHeight 447
/FontFile2 5 0 R
>>
endobj

Text object:
4 0 obj
<</Length 55 >>
stream
BT
/F1 12 Tf
100 100 Td
(Привет, мир!) Tj
ET
endstream
endobj

Then i tried creating a CMAP:
7 0 obj
<<
/Length 450
>>
stream
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<<  /Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (UCS)
/Supplement 9
>> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
9 beginbfchar
<0004> <0021>
<000F> <002C>
<0249> <041F>
<025C> <0432>
<025F> <0435>
<0262> <0438>
<0266> <043C>
<026A> <0440>
<026C> <0442>
endbfchar
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end
endstream
endobj

But for some reason i get blank squares instead of my letters, i used some tools to validate my PDF and i got:
Validating file "temp.pdf" for conformance level pdf1.6

The glyph for character 53407 in font 'MUGZNE+Times-Roman' is missing.

The glyph for character 53632 in font 'MUGZNE+Times-Roman' is missing.

The glyph for character 53432 in font 'MUGZNE+Times-Roman' is missing.

The glyph for character 53426 in font 'MUGZNE+Times-Roman' is missing.

The glyph for character 53429 in font 'MUGZNE+Times-Roman' is missing.

The glyph for character 53634 in font 'MUGZNE+Times-Roman' is missing.

The glyph for character 11296 in font 'MUGZNE+Times-Roman' is missing.

The glyph for character 53436 in font 'MUGZNE+Times-Roman' is missing.

The value of the show text string of an operand is out of range.

The glyph for character 8448 in font 'MUGZNE+Times-Roman' is missing.

The document does not conform to the requested standard.

The file format (header, trailer, objects, xref, streams) is corrupted.

The document contains fonts without embedded font programs or encoding information (CMAPs).

The document does not conform to the PDF 1.6 standard.

What's the problem with letters not displaying properly?
I tried to use another font or to make font object the other way:
BT
/F4 14.666667 Tf
1 0 0 -1 0 .62304592 Tm
0 -13.0696621 Td <0249> Tj
10.5842743 0 Td <026A> Tj
7.328125 0 Td <0262> Tj
7.8433838 0 Td <025C> Tj
6.8342743 0 Td <025F> Tj
6.5051422 0 Td <026C> Tj
5.3020935 0 Td <000F> Tj
ET

But nothing seems to work

@KJ thank, that worked! Only now the letters are upside-down for some reason...

@KJ nvm the problem was with Tm, thank you good sir!
